# unable to locate trace definition file for microsoft sql server version 10.50.0

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

I try  to create a new trace in sql server profiler. got following error:

unable to locate trace definition file for microsoft sql server version 10.50.0

the database I connected to is sql server 10.50.2500.   my sql server management studio is 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 ).

I searched this problem on google, couldn't anything helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You need to log onto a SQL 2008 R2 server and grab the files in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Profiler\TraceDefinitions" (including the subfolder) and put them into the same location on your machine.  Specifically you need the files which end in "10.50.0"

That or upgrade your client tools to the SQL 2008 R2 version.